# mongoDB + Mongoose + Angularjs :Mocha Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'tag' of null

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose, mocha.js

I am unit testing my dao method with mocha and i have an issue while launching mocha :

here is my dao method :

```
    exports.update = function(req, res) {
  var profilTag = new ProfilTag(req.body);
  ProfilTag.findById(profilTag._id, function(err, item) {
    if (err) {
      res.send({
        'result': 'error'
      });
    } else {
      item.tag = profilTag.tag;
      item.texte = profilTag.texte;
      item.tagName = profilTag.tagName;
      item.police = profilTag.police;
      item.taille = profilTag.taille;
      item.interligne = profilTag.interligne;
      item.styleValue = profilTag.styleValue;

      item.save(item, function() {
        res.send({
          'result': 'error'
        });
      });
    }
  });
};
```

and its unit test using Mocha :

```
    it('Dao:ProfilTag:update', function(done) {
    app.post('/updateProfilTag', function(req, res) {
        req.body = {
            _id: '52e52e61c94dbc474373ea68',
            tag: '52e18fb80084242442000005',
            texte: '<p>ModifiedText</p>',
            tagName: 'ModifiedTagName',
            police: 'ModifiedPolice',
            taille: 'ModifiedTaille',
            interligne: 'ModifiedInterligne',
            styleValue: 'ModifiedStyleValue'
        };
        profilTagDao.update(req, res);
    });
    request(app).post('/updateProfilTag').expect(200, done);
});
```

My Mongoose schema is the following :

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var profilTagSchema = new Schema({
    profil: {type: String},
    tag: {type: String},
    texte: {    type: String},
    tagName: {type: String},
    police: {type: String},
    taille: {type: String},
    interligne: {type: String},
    styleValue: {type: String}

});

/**
 * Statics
 */
profilTagSchema.statics = {
    load: function(id, cb) {
        this.findOne({
            _id: id
        }).exec(cb);
    }
};

var ProfilTag = mongoose.model('ProfilTag', profilTagSchema);
```

i have ignored profil in the dao method.

when i launch Mocha to unit test my method it is telling me this message ( command line )

> ```
>  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'tag' of null
> ```

Is there a way to ignore some properties ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ignore some properties". What's happening in your code is that somewhere your code tries to do something like ``null.tag = "whatever"``. Probably you have a variable that unexpectedly resolves to ``null``. What line generates your ``TypeError``. You should be able to tell from the stack trace.